# Translate dynamic string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, string

I am trying to find a string inside a class span tag and replace the string with jQuery.

Color is random and dynamic so i need to find color in English and translate it to Italia.

I have around 14 colors to translate.

```
'Black'
'Blue'
'Gold'
'Orange'
```

To

```
'Nero'
'Blu'
'Oro'
'Arancia'
```

Example:

```
<div class="short-features">
  <!-- Heading Area -->
  <div class="heading-panel">
    <h3 class="main-title text-left">Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <span><strong>Color</strong> :</span> Black
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding"></div>
</div>
```

Attempt:

```
$(".short-features .col-md-4")
    .has('span')
    .replaceWith("<span><strong>Color</strong> :</span>Nero</div>");
```

The above code works but since the color is dynamic changes according to the page, I need to modify the jQuery to find the string Black and replace it with Nero.

Comment: It would be more prudent to change the HTML structure and target specific element.  I would wrap 'Black' in a span i.e. `<span class="color">Black</span>` and then use `$( ".short-features .col-md-4 .color" ).text( "Nero" );`

Comment: In addition to the above, you could use the colour as the class or a data attribute, eg `<span data-color='black'>Black</span>` then you can have dynamic colour replacements across any language `$("[data-color=black]").text("Nero");`